# What are FARs & where can I find them? What is FAR 23, 25, 135, etc?

Tags: faa-regulations

The FARs (or **Federal Aviation Regulations**) are the regulations imposed by the FAA on aviation within the United States.

Many questions make reference to FAR 23, or FAR 91 etc. What are each of these? Where can one lookup the text?

Comment: See also: [Should we allow questions asking for resources?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15)

Comment: I don't think this qualifies so much as "asking for resources" - I know a lot of people who get halfway through ground school before realizing that the FAR/AIM is (a) 2 different books glued together, and (b) really just a paper copy of the Code of Federal Regulations that they can look up on their iPrecious for free :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US the "Federal Aviation Regulations" (FARs) is shorthand for referring to Title 14 of the Code of Federal Regulations.

You can browse all sections of FARs at [ECFR.Gov](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14tab_02.tpl).

FAR 23, for example, covers airworthiness standards. [§ 23.25](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:1.0.1.3.10&rgn=div5#14:1.0.1.3.10.2.59.3) regulates weight limits.

Comment: In addition to the eCFR version of the FARs (which is kept current with changes in near-real-time as new legislation passes) you can also get bound copies of the FARs (usually with a copy of the [AIM](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/index.htm) tacked on to the back) at pretty much any pilot shop. With the abundance of excellent electronic versions the paper is mostly useful as a 1.5-lb ballast for weight & balance :-)

Answer (score 4):

## FARs on the web

There are several sites on the web, but my favorite is the FAA's own Regulatory and Guidance Library at http://rgl.faa.gov/.  If you click the [Code of Federal Regulations](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset) link on their main page, you can look at current ***and historical regulations as well as preamble information, links to the dockets, NPRM's, and more***.  Just click on "By Part" under the "Current CFR" section, and you can browse through each section. If you then scroll down, you will find the two that you asked about:

> Part 23 - AIRWORTHINESS STANDARDS: NORMAL, UTILITY, ACROBATIC, AND COMMUTER CATEGORY AIRPLANES

and

> Part 91 - GENERAL OPERATING AND FLIGHT RULES

Click the arrow next to each part and it will show links to the full text of each regulation.

## Extra Info

The site also includes the following databases:

- Advisory Circulars

  - Draft Advisory Circulars
- Airworthiness Directives

  - AD NPRMs
- CARs/CAMs/Aero-Bulletins
- Code of Federal Regulations

  - CFR NPRMs
  - CFR Final Rules
- Equivalent Levels of Safety
- Exemptions
- Orders/Notices
- Parts Manufacturer Approvals
- Policy
- Regulatory Basis Tool
- Special Airworthiness Information Bulletins
- Special Conditions
- Supplemental Type Certificates
- Technical Standard Orders and Index
- Type Certificate Data Sheets